# Generate permutations between values of different data frames in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a base R solution that will help me generate combinations of data frame values. I have two data frames;

```
[df1]
Col1Name    Col1Reference
first   a
first   b
first   c

[df2]
Col2Name    Col2Reference
second  a
third   b
```

I want to generate a new data frame, such that new columns from [df2] are assigned against those of [df1] as follows;

```
Col1Name    Col1Reference   Col2Name    Col2Reference
first   a   second  a
first   b   second  a
first   c   second  a
first   a   third   b
first   b   third   b
first   c   thid    b
```

is anybody able to help? any advice would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
cbind(df1[rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)),nrow(df2)),],
      df2[rep(seq_len(nrow(df2)),each=nrow(df1)),])
#    Col1Name Col1Reference Col2Name Col2Reference
#1      first             a   second             a
#2      first             b   second             a
#3      first             c   second             a
#1.1    first             a    third             b
#2.1    first             b    third             b
#3.1    first             c    third             b
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach based on `expand.grid`:

```
df1= data.frame(col1="first",col2=letters[1:3],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2= data.frame(col1=c("second","third"),col2=letters[1:2],stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

indices=expand.grid(1:nrow(df1),1:nrow(df2))
cbind(df1[indices[,1],],df2[indices[,2],])
```

with result (you may just want to adjust rownames)

```
     col1 col2   col1 col2
1   first    a second    a
2   first    b second    a
3   first    c second    a
1.1 first    a  third    b
2.1 first    b  third    b
3.1 first    c  third    b
```